# Firebird index not used when using JOIN, why?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I'm using FB 2.5.5 and I'm trying to understand why a very simple query does not use an index and thus takes forever to execute. I've read a lot of articles about why existing indices might be ignored by the query optimizer but I'm not understanding how it can happens in my case. I recomputed the selectivity for all my indices within IB Expert, and I've also done a backup/restore of the database to be sure I wasn't missing something.

The index selectivity, as displayed by IB Expert, is approx 0,000024 - which is far from 1 :

```
CREATE INDEX TVERSIONS_IDX_LASTMODDATE ON TVERSIONS (LASTMODDATE)
```

The table I'm querying contains approx. 2M records :

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TVERSIONS
2479518
```

I'm trying to fetch all records based on the LASTMODDATE field (TIMETSAMP, indexed by TVERSIONS_IDX_LASTMODDATE). An oversimplified version of the query would be :

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TVERSIONS WHERE LASTMODDATE > :TheDate
```

In this case, the execution plan shows that the index is actually used :

```
Plan
PLAN (TVERSIONS INDEX (TVERSIONS_IDX_LASTMODDATE))
```

...and records matching the condition are fetched very quickly :

```
------ Performance info ------
Prepare time = 172ms
Execute time = 16ms <----
Avg fetch time = 16,00 ms
Current memory = 2 714 672
Max memory = 10 128 480
Memory buffers = 90
Reads from disk to cache = 57
Writes from cache to disk = 0
Fetches from cache = 387
```

Now, the "real" query fetches *the same fields* using the *same condition* on LASTMODDATE but adds a JOIN over 3 tables :

```
SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TVERSIONS
    JOIN TFILES ON TFILES.ID = TVERSIONS.FILEID
    JOIN TROOTS ON TROOTS.ID = TFILES.ROOTID
    JOIN TUSERSBACKUPS ON TROOTS.BACKUPID = TUSERSBACKUPS.BACKUPID
    WHERE TUSERSBACKUPS.USERID= :UserID
    AND TVERSIONS.LASTMODDATE >:TheDate
```

Now the query plan **does not use the index anymore** :

```
Plan
PLAN JOIN (TUSERSBACKUPS INDEX (RDB$FOREIGN4), TROOTS INDEX (RDB$FOREIGN3), TFILES INDEX (RDB$FOREIGN2), TVERSIONS INDEX (RDB$FOREIGN6))
```

Without any surprise execution time is **far more slower** (approx. 1 minute):

```
------ Performance info ------
Prepare time = 329ms
Execute time = 53s 593ms <---
Avg fetch time = 53 593,00 ms
Current memory = 3 044 736
Max memory = 10 128 480
Memory buffers = 90
Reads from disk to cache = 55 732
Writes from cache to disk = 0
Fetches from cache = 6 952 648
```

In other words, searching the WHOLE table is magnitude faster than searching into a subset of rows returned by JOIN.

I can't understand why the index on the LASTMODDATE field is not used anymore just because I'm adding the join clause. The selectivity of the index is good and the query is very simple. What do I miss ?

Comment: The Firebird optimizer doesn't always make the right choices, you might want to try reordering the joins, or using a (common) table expression.

Answer (score 2):

It seems Firebird decided to start with condition `TUSERSBACKUPS.USERID=:UserID` using index `RDB$FOREIGN4`. Probably it happens because you have here equality, and for condition `TVERSIONS.LASTMODDATE >:TheDate` you have inequality which could lead to potentially larger set of records (for example if `TheDate` is a date 200 years ago it will include the whole table).

To force Firebird use a plan which you (but not its optimizer) prefer - use `PLAN` clause, see http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq224/

Answer (score 0):

I think I've understood what happened, and... I guess it was my fault.

I forgot that the table I'm querying has been "denormalized" to avoid such long JOINs. The problematic query can indeed by rewritten in a much shorter way :

```
SELECT COUNT(TVERSIONS.ID) FROM TVERSIONS
    JOIN TUSERSBACKUPS ON TUSERSBACKUPS.BACKUPID = TVERSIONS.RD_BACKUPID
    WHERE TUSERSBACKUPS.USERID= :UserID
    AND TVERSIONS.LASTMODDATE >:TheDate
```

This one properly uses the indices I set before and has a very short execution time.

I have the impression that when Firebird detects you're deliberately using a sub-optimal path to access records in a table it does not even try to use your indices and let you shoot yourself in the foot...

Anyway, the problem is solved. Thank you all for your suggestions.